# Installing XCTU To Raspbian Jessie with Exagear Desktop

Tags: linux, installation, filesystems, raspbian, xbee

I'm trying to run Linux x86 XCTU (software for XBee controllers) off the guest image generated by Exagear (to execute x86 on Raspberry Pi 2). It fails with the error log file seen below. I tried installing the SWT library (downloaded from Eclipse) in /home/pi. However, it shows the same error message again. What am I doing wrong? What could I do differently ? Is there an easier way to do this? Any suggestions and leads would be much appreciated.

```
    !SESSION 2016-05-01 20:40:42.658 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=unknown
    java.version=1.7.0_21
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
    Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -clearPersistedState

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-05-01 20:41:03.414
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
/opt/Digi/XCTU-NG/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/146/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4236.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path
/home/pi/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk-4236.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Can't load library: /home/pi/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk.so

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:22)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:133)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:653)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
at com.digi.xctung.application.XctungApplication.start(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your system missing `libgtk-x11-2`. You can install it by following command

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```